# keycloak map attributes to permission

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Currently i am trying to add a large amount of users to keycloak, they have the attribute "impersonsate" over which i want to decide which of the users may impersonate.

Is there a way to use keycloaks built-in features to distribute the appropriate permission depending on this attribute?

If not, is there a way to do it within the UserProviderInterface or similar?
Im adding the users using this Interface, so if theres a possibility, i could just decide inside my provider if the permission should be set.

Comment: I would suggest you to assign impersonation role to the user so that user can access impersonation functionality

Comment: You mean in code or by hand? There are way too much users to do it by hand, so i need a policies do does it automatic or some functionality in my code.

Comment: You can write a script to assign roles automatically by calling keycloak api.